# ¿"Mismo de" o "mismo que"?

Tags: gramática, redacción

Me acaban de corregir dos veces en un documento, y me pongo muy odioso cuando me critican la redacción. Yo siempre he dicho "mismo de":

> El mismo sistema **de** antes.
>
> Hay que instalarlo en el mismo servidor **del** otro sistema.

Pero me insisten en que es así:

> El mismo sistema **que** antes.
>
> Hay que instalarlo en el mismo servidor **que el** otro sistema.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta?

Comment: Rodrigo, observo que creaste la etiqueta [tag:corrección] en esta pregunta y luego otras la han utilizado. ¿Te parece que es necesaria o podríamos diluirla dentro de [tag:gramática]? Al fin y al cabo, si lo que quiere es consultar si algo es correcto, esta es una propiedad "meta" de la pregunta, consustancial a toda pregunta de por aquí.

Comment: @fedorqui Por supuesto, elimínala. Probablemente la creé para obtener un bounty o algo así, ya no recuerdo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según la RAE:

> mismo, ma.  (Del lat. vulg. *metipsĭmus, combinación del elemento
>   enfático -met, que se añadía a los prons. pers., y un sup. de ipse, el
>   mismo).
>   1. adj. Idéntico, no otro. Este pobre es el mismo a quien ayer socorrí. Esa espada es la misma que sirvió a mi padre.
>   2. adj. Exactamente igual. De la misma forma. Del mismo color.
>   3. adj. U., por pleonasmo, añadido a los pronombres personales y a algunos adverbios para dar más energía a lo que se dice. Yo mismo lo
>   haré. Ella misma se condena. Hoy mismo lo veré. Aquí mismo te espero.

Las dos formas son correctas, pero no se pueden usar indistintamente:

"Yo soy el mismo de siempre."  "Yo soy el mismo que siempre (he sido)." (Ambas correctas.)

"Tengo el mismo que tú."  "Tengo el mismo de tú." (La segunda es incorrecta.)

En conclusión, de acuerdo a cómo continúe la oración es cómo se debe elegir una u otra.

Answer (score 5):

Las reglas de la [RAE para "mismo/a"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=apcQb0FGPD6m7ysHSu) indican en el punto 4:

> Cuando forma parte de **estructuras comparativas**, con el sentido de ‘igual’, bien con valor nominal (‘la misma cosa’), bien con valor adverbial (‘de la misma manera’), el segundo término de comparación va introducido por la conjunción **'que'**.

Entiendo que este es el uso que estás haciendo en los dos ejemplos de tu pregunta. Así que sí, para comparar (entre sistemas o servidores, etc.) hay que usar `mismo que` y no `mismo de`.